# Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping error even after creating mappingProfile

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-6.0

Whenever I'm trying to call mapper, I get this error :

> Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

I added automapper in startup class(Program.cs)

```
services.SetupControllers();
services.SetupSwagger();
services.SetupCache(configuration);
services.SetupAuthentication(configuration);
services.SetupAuthorization();
services.SetupAutoMapper();
services.SetupBusiness<IPersonManager, PersonManager>(); //Using automapper in PersonManager
services.SetupRepositories();
services.SetupDatabase<myDbContext>(configuration, "LDS");
```

AutoMapperExtension

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection SetupAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly? assembly = null) =>
        services.AddAutoMapper(assembly ?? Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
}
```

MappingProfileClass

```
public class ScoreMappingProfile: Profile
{
    public ScoreMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<PersonScoreModel, PersonScoreEntity>();
    }
}
```

Code that causes error in PersonManager.

```
   private List<PersonScoreEntity> MapModelToEntity(List<PersonScoreModel> personModels)
    {
        List<PersonScoreEntity> personEntities = new List<PersonScoreEntity>();
        foreach (var personModel in personModels)
        {
            var mapped = _mapper.Map<PersonScoreEntity>(personModel); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            personEntities.Add(mapped);
        }
        return personEntities;
    }
```

PersonScoreEntity

```
public class PersonScoreEntity: EntityBase
{
    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }

    public Guid PopulationId { get; set; }
    
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public PopulationEntity Population { get; set; } = null!;

    public UserEntity User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

PersonModel

```
public class PersonScoreModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid PopulationId { get; set; }

    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }
}
```

Similar question are present on stackoverflow, I couldn't find solution that would fit my problem

Comment: Is `RoleMappingProfile` / `ScoreMappingProfile` a typo? Is `RoleMappingProfile` in the assembly that calls `SetupAutoMapper`? Does `PersonScoreModel` have any reference-type properties that need their own `Profile`?

Comment: Do you have a subobject in `PersonScoreModel`? Show your classes for `PersonScoreModel` and `PersonScoreEntity` please.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay entity object has reference object

Comment: @chambo added classes

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that `ScoreMappingProfile` is defined in a different project (assembly) to your `Startup.cs`.

Comment: @IanKemp You are a legit psychic, That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firs of all, you need to say which profile you need to map:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(YourProfile);
```

In your profile, you need to specify which object is converted to which object and vice versa:

```
public StudentProfile()
{
    CreateMap<PersonScoreModel, PersonScoreEntity>();
    CreateMap<PersonScoreEntity, PersonScoreModel>();
}
```

and your entities must have the same parameters as your model.
Here is a link which helps me when i have simmilar task:
[Getting Started Guide](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)